# Displaying Quotes using ChoiceFormat pattern

Tags: java, format, pattern-matching

I am trying to display a message having quotes besides the format element using ChoiceFormat. Using the pattern, the quote doesn't get printed but using the programmatic way as in java docs for ChoiceFormat it works fine. Any clues?

```
Object[] testArgs = { "Navin", 0 };
// Using Pattern
System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("You commented on {1,choice,0#{0}''s diary|1#many diaries}", testArgs));

// Creating programmatically
MessageFormat form = new MessageFormat("You commented on {1}");
double[] limits = { 0, 1 };
String[] part = { "{0}''s diary", "many diaries" };
ChoiceFormat cform = new ChoiceFormat(limits, part);
form.setFormatByArgumentIndex(1, cform);

System.out.println(form.format(testArgs));
```

Gives the output:

You commented on Navins diary

You commented on Navin's diary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put another set of single quotes, as in:

```
System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("You commented on {1,choice,0#{0}''''s diary|1#many diaries}", testArgs));
```

This should print:

*You commented on Navin's diary*